# Installing DevedeNG in kali linux, but missing python dependency it says is already installed

Tags: software-installation, python, kali-linux

[image: This is the error i receive in command prompt.]

As you can see in the picture it says dependency is not satisfiable, but when I try to install the latest version of python3 the command prompt tells me i have the latest version installed.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error I receive after trying to follow the steps @eyoung100 provided me, I have made significant progress but more help is required and would be appreciated.

```
root@kali:~# sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 160, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 584, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

Comment: Check the version. The screen shot shows that the dependency is >= 3.3.2-2~.

Comment: Okay, i am recently new to kali linux, would you be able to tell me the file path and how to check it

Comment: Start by running `python3 --version` to make sure you have a usable version.

Comment: Okay, i am running python version 3.2.3, and the command prompt tells me i'm on the latest version. So im guessing this means i have to find an older version of DevedeNG? thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: That version is from 2012. I would try to install a newer version of python.

Comment: I have tried this, and it says im on the newest version, is there a way to install the latest version. maybe not through command prompt?

Comment: @user1794469 I converted your answer to a comment since it was not answering the question. Feel free to post a new answer explaining how the OP could install the needed version of python.

Comment: Wow, I learn something new every day.  See update. Sorry for the delay, but the formatting took me awhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on user1794469's converted comment, since Kali is based on Debian, you can add a PPA containing a newer version of python.  Follow these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install -y python3.3 python3.3-dev`

Steps taken from [Ronald Bradford's Blog Entry](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/installing-python-3-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts-2015-04-29/), as these were more recent than [this entry on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3/290283#290283), which if I had to guess would be where Ronald found the answer 1st.

---

This repository contains both old(hence dead) and new versions of python(a species of snake), combine to create *deadsnakes*(must give a thumbs up for humor).  See the [Official WebPPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes)

---

### A Word of Caution

Please do not remove or replace the original Python3 Version, since this was the version that came installed in Kali.  As Ronald Bradford points out, python versions can be installed side by side.  If you were to remove it, you might have problems with scripts looking for the version you removed.

---

### Update

Because Kali Linux is used for the specialized application of [penetration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test), the ability of adding third-party repositories, a.k.a PPA's (Personal Package Archive's) isn't available. Quoted from *BlackMoreOps, link below*:

> Debian allows users to add and use PPA repositories by an application
>   named add-apt-repository however, Kali Linux didn’t include this in
>   their default package list. With Kali, because this is a special
>   purpose application and certain modifications were made to make it
>   work for what it does best (Penetration Test), there’s a chance that
>   by adding untested and unsupported PPA repositories and application
>   you might end up breaking your installation.

I must admit that I did not know this functionality was removed.  Fear not, as we can add it back.

### Explanation

This functionality was removed because the code stored on the hosted PPA cannot be verified as secure by the Kali Maintainers.  As such, **use the following procedure at your own risk**!  Before following the steps listed in my original answer, we must manually add the command for apt add-repository. To do so, see [this blog entry at BlackMoreOps](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/02/21/kali-linux-add-ppa-repository-add-apt-repository/).  I tried adding it manually here, but did not realize there were multiple methods after adding the command, plus the pictures speak 1,000 words.(If the link I pointed you to ever goes link-dead, let me know and I'll find it again) As such, I'll comment on the two approaches.

1. To stay with the original implementation design that Kali intended, follow steps 1 - 3, and test with 4.
2. To mimic another OS (specifically the Ubuntu derivatives), follow steps 1, 2, and 5, and test with 4. Remember to update **Step 5b** with the [newer official codenames from the Ubuntu Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames).
3. If you use Steps 1,2, and 5, remember that you can revert back to Kali by reading the Gotcha section.

See Also [this Post at the Kali Forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?292-Add-apt-repository), which uses the same type of approach to add repositories from all Debian based derivatives, and may include Debian itself.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the great answer, and the original commenter for his answers you both helped alot, how do i thumps up your answers. or recognize you for your help? This solved my problem

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  To mark an answer "correct," you should see a checkmark below my vote counter.  Since you wrote the question, you're the only one who can choose an answer.  In case you don't know where the vote counter is, I'll give you your first 10 points.

Comment: I have edited my original question to show the errors i received when following the instructions i received from @eyoung100 further help would be appreciated

Comment: @NickWade In case you didn't see my comment in your original question, I've updated my answer, with the help you asked for.

Comment: Okay thanks again, im currently using steps 1-4 and its going great, stuck on step 2 when adding the  "vi add-apt repository" after adding the code there was no option to save file like it asks.

Comment: Do you have `nano`?  I'm in the camp that doesn't like `vi`, so I'd just replace the editor :)

Comment: yes i do have nano but it also doesnt have a save option? not that i can see anyway.

Comment: Use Ctrl +X in `nano`, then Y to Save

Comment: Okay, i have followed all steps and everything added successfully, but upon trying to install the latest python version the command prompt gave me this message "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.3-dev : Depends: libpython3.3 (= 3.3.1-1+oneiric1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: That's OK, `python-3.3-dev` isn't needed unless you're developing new python plugins, apps etc

Comment: okay so which should i install?

Comment: Just `python-3.3` is all you need...

Comment: i installed 3.3, and it needs atleast 3.3.2-2, it says 3.3 isnt enough

Comment: Leave 3.3 installed and try the command `sudo apt-get install -y python3.4`

Comment: yea it said it couldnt find the regex, but i found if i searched for an older version of devedeNG and it let me install it, and then just update from the prompt, i got everything working now thank you guys so much